# Timer That Stops After a Minute

Tags: python

I have this code that will ask the user a question and it will tell them if they are correct or wrong. Now I want to add a part that will stop asking questions after a minute.

```py
import random 
def random_problem(num_operations):
  eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))
  for _ in range(num_operations):
    eq += random.choice(["+"])
    eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))
  return eq 

while True:
  problem = random_problem(1) 
  ask=int(input(problem +": ")) 
  solution = eval(problem)
  if ask == solution: 
    print("correct")
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to stop even if idling waiting for input?

Comment: No, Thanks for the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but here's a simple snippet that you can tweak to your liking.

Essentially, you can use the `time` module to calculate the elapsed time. The snippet will break out of the while loop only when a minute has been elapsed.

```
import random 
import time

def random_problem(num_operations):
  eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))
  for _ in range(num_operations):
    eq += random.choice(["+"])
    eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))
  return eq 

start = time.time()
seconds = 60

while time.time() - start < seconds:
  problem = random_problem(1) 
  ask=int(input(problem +": ")) 
  solution = eval(problem)
  if ask == solution: 
    print("correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will automatically stops asking questions ether 60 seconds elapsed or the layer has found the correct answer

```
import random
from time import perf_counter


def random_problem(num_operations):
   eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))
   for _ in range(num_operations):
      eq += random.choice(["+"])
      eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))
   return eq


start = perf_counter()

while True:

if perf_counter() - start >= 60:
    break

problem = random_problem(1)
ask = int(input(problem + ": "))
solution = eval(problem)
if ask == solution:
    print("correct")
    break
```

Comment: I get an error on line two 'from time import perfcounter'

Comment: @Ben i forgot the "_" I updated the code now it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` module to implement what you want.

```py
import random 
import time

def random_problem(num_operations):
  eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))
  for _ in range(num_operations):
    eq += random.choice(["+"])
    eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))
  return eq 

start = time.time()

while True:
  elapsed = time.time() - start
  if elapsed > 60:
    break
  problem = random_problem(1) 
  ask=int(input(problem +": ")) 
  solution = eval(problem)
  if ask == solution: 
    print("correct")
```

Comment: My only question is that can you still run the check algo at the same time while running the timer because when I ran all of the answers after you put in response it would not tell you if you were not wrong or right.

Comment: @Ben While it doesn't run a timer, it checks the *elapsed time* by subtracting the current time from the start time. Since *time* given by `time.time()` is calculated by your OS, it would not be too wrong to say that **timer** and your program are running simultaneously.
Meanwhile, if you literally want to run **your timer** simultaneously with your `random_problem`, consider using [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to keep on listening to user inputs, checking how much time has passed could be a solution.

```
import random
import time


def random_problem(num_operations):
    eq = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    for _ in range(num_operations):
        eq += random.choice(["+"])
        eq += str(random.randint(1, 100))
    return eq


# could be changed to time.time(). perf_counter offers better accuracy
start_time = time.perf_counter()

while True:
    problem = random_problem(1)
    ask = int(input(problem + ": "))
    solution = eval(problem)
    if ask == solution:
        print("correct")

    if time.perf_counter() - start_time > 60:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python already have a built-in module that counts the time since the object time was created (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

First you need to import that module and then initialize the "timer", for example:

```
import time

start = time.time()
end = time.time() - start
```

The variable `end` will return the time between the `start` variable definition and the `end` variable definition.

In your case you need to start the time counting outside your `while` loop, put a `clock` inside your `while` loop that will countabilize the time passed each iteration and turn the condition for the `while` loop `False` when the time reached the limit.

```
import time
...
start_time = time.time() 
running = True

while running:

    timer = time.time() - start_time

    if timer < 60:
        problem = random_problem(1) 
        ask=int(input(problem +": ")) 
        solution = eval(problem)
        if ask == solution: 
            print("correct") 
    else:
        running = False
```